# uinstall ubuntu 10.04 and download windows 8 from dreamspark free for students

Tags: 10.04

I am very new to computers and want to remove ubuntu 10.04 on my recycled pc from alameda county computer resource center which seems to have had windows vista prior to linux (there is a windows vista sticker next to the intel sticker) and then download windows 8 pro for free for students at dreamspark.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not clairvoyant, and cannot state with any certainty that your computer absolutely will not run windows remotely well, I feel confident enough to bet on it, and I rarely gamble.

The reason I am so sure have a lot to do with the operating system which is on it.  You see, version 10.04 of Ubuntu was the very last generation before Unity, meaning that it's graphics and memory demands were less than slightly later operating systems have been ever since.  Also, the operating system is four and a half years old, meaning that the computer is probably between 6-10 years old, but again, I'm speculating.

Your computer may not be worth much, but it is actually worth significantly more now, with an out-of-date working installation of Ubuntu on it, than it will be if you disable even that.

If you wish to verify my assessment, please install [System Profiler and Benchmark](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/hardinfo/), and update your request with such information as the type of CPU, the amount of RAM, and any other such information as you may glean from it.